# Apostrophe with company names

Tags: apostrophe

How do I say this?

> Zowie mice are better than Logitech.

> Zowie's mice are better than Logitech's.

> Zowies are better than Logitechs.

Comment: All three are possible.

Comment: Which one is more common and natural?

Comment: That is a matter of opinion.

Comment: I wouldn't use the first example without adding *mice* after *Logitech*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Zowie's mice are better than Logitech's.

is correct and a common way to express this comparison.

> Zowie mice are better than Logitech. [image: incorrect as shown by red X]

does not work. It could be rephrased as:

> - Zowie mice are better than Logitech mice.
> - Zowie mice are better than Logitech ones.
> - Zowie mice are better than mice from Logitech.

However, if "meece"were the brand name or nickname of a kind of mouse, one might say:

> - Zowie mice are better than meece.

The third example:

> Zowies are better than Logitechs [image: incorrect as shown by red X]

works only if "Zowies" and "Logitechs" are commonly used to refer to the particular types of mouse, or the specific products, which in fact they are not. So one might say

> - Fords are better than Chevys.
> - Whoppers are better than Big macs.
> - Colts are better than Glocks.

but not

> Intels are better than AMDs. [image: incorect as shown by red X]